# combining data between two time stamps from two files

Tags: python, file, sorting, text, compare

I have two files to be compared and the words in one file is split into multiple segments of another file. I need to find a way to map the segments with the original word/phrase.

In the given files I use the timestart and time end of a word in Chinese and compared the phoneset that come under this time stamp and printed those values for the Chinese word.

The files I used are:
reference file: https://ufile.io/7lze7
segments file: https://ufile.io/rysz4

The code I have tried so far:

```
    outfile=open("lexlog",'w')

    phoneme=[]
    with open("ref.txt"+file,'r') as sylfile:
        for lines in sylfile:
            start,end,syl=lines.split()
            #print "from syl "+start,end
            with open("hyp.txt", 'r') as phnfile:
                for line in phnfile:
                    startphn, endphn, sylphn = line.split()
                    if (startphn>=start) and (endphn<=end) and (startphn<endphn):
                        phoneme.append(sylphn)
                        print `enter code here`sylphn
                        outfile.write(startphn+" "+start+" "+endphn+" "+end)
                print file,syl,' '.join(phoneme)
                outfile.write(file+" "+syl+" "+' '.join(phoneme)+"\n")
                phoneme=[]
```

The result I expect is in the form of:

```
ref.txt !SIL SIL
ref.txt 非 F EI
ref.txt 生 SH AH NG
ref.txt 物 U
ref.txt 物 U
ref.txt 體 T I
ref.txt 也 I E
ref.txt 會 H U EI
ref.txt 有 I OU 
ref.txt 一 I
ref.txt 種 ZH O NG
ref.txt 被 B EI
ref.txt 稱 CH AH NG
ref.txt 作 Z U O
ref.txt 自 Z IH
ref.txt 殺 SH A
ref.txt 的 D AH
ref.txt 設 SH AH
ref.txt 計 J I
ref.txt !SIL SIL
ref.txt 例 L I
ref.txt 如 R U
ref.txt !SIL SIL
ref.txt 人 R AH N
ref.txt 工 G O NG
ref.txt 智 ZH IH
ref.txt 慧 H U EI
ref.txt !SIL SIL
ref.txt 在 Z AI
ref.txt 被 B EI
ref.txt 電 D I E N
ref.txt 腦 N AU
ref.txt 病 B I NG
ref.txt 毒 D U
ref.txt 入 R U
ref.txt 侵 Q I N
ref.txt 的 D AH
ref.txt 情 Q I NG
ref.txt 況 K U A NG
ref.txt 下 X I A
ref.txt !SIL SIL
ref.txt 會 H U EI
ref.txt 啟 Q I
ref.txt 動 D O NG
ref.txt 殺 SH A
ref.txt 毒 D U
ref.txt 程 CH AH NG
ref.txt 系 X I
ref.txt !SIL SIL
ref.txt 同 T O NG
ref.txt 時 SH IH
ref.txt 刪 SH A N
ref.txt 除 CH U
ref.txt 自 Z IH
ref.txt 己 J I
ref.txt 體 T I
ref.txt 內 N EI
ref.txt 的 D AH
ref.txt 檔 D A NG
ref.txt 案 A N
ref.txt !SIL SIL
```

but the output is:

```
ref.txt !SIL SIL 
ref.txt 非 F EI 
ref.txt 生 SH AH NG 
ref.txt 物 U 
ref.txt 物 U 
ref.txt 體 T I 
ref.txt 也 I E 
ref.txt 會 H U EI 
ref.txt 有 I OU A D U CH AH NG X I SIL T O NG SH IH SH A N CH U Z IH J I T I N EI D AH D A NG A N SIL 
ref.txt 一 I 
ref.txt 種 ZH O NG 
ref.txt 被 B EI 
ref.txt 稱 CH AH NG 
ref.txt 作 Z U O 
ref.txt 自 Z IH 
ref.txt 殺 SH A 
ref.txt 的 D AH 
ref.txt 設 SH AH 
ref.txt 計 J I 
ref.txt !SIL SIL 
ref.txt 例 L I 
ref.txt 如 R U 
ref.txt !SIL SIL 
ref.txt 人 R AH N 
ref.txt 工 G O NG 
ref.txt 智 ZH IH 
ref.txt 慧 H U EI 
ref.txt !SIL SIL 
ref.txt 在 Z AI 
ref.txt 被 B EI 
ref.txt 電 D I E N 
ref.txt 腦 N AU 
ref.txt 病 B I NG 
ref.txt 毒 D U 
ref.txt 入 R U 
ref.txt 侵 Q I N 
ref.txt 的 D AH 
ref.txt 情 Q I NG 
ref.txt 況 K U A NG 
ref.txt 下 X I A 
ref.txt !SIL SIL 
ref.txt 會 H U EI 
ref.txt 啟 Q I 
ref.txt 動 D O NG 
ref.txt 殺  
ref.txt 毒 D U 
ref.txt 程 CH AH NG 
ref.txt 系 X I 
ref.txt !SIL SIL 
ref.txt 同 T O NG 
ref.txt 時 SH IH 
ref.txt 刪 SH A N 
ref.txt 除 CH U 
ref.txt 自 Z IH 
ref.txt 己 J I 
ref.txt 體 T I 
ref.txt 內 N EI 
ref.txt 的 D AH 
ref.txt 檔 D A NG 
ref.txt 案 A N 
ref.txt !SIL SIL
```

Somehow the eighth line in the output gets a different result to what I expected. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Part of you problem is you are comparing strings. Your first two columns need to be converted to floats. e.g. `row = line.split()` and `startphn, endphn, sylphn = float(row[0]), float(row[1]), row[2]`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to understand the required output, but you do seem to be trying to output the time values too.

You are reading the data from each files in as strings. The first two columns from each of the rows needs to be converted into a float, otherwise your comparisons will be done on string values, not numerical values. Here I convert the the first two values to floats.

```
import csv
file = ''

with open("lexlog.txt", 'wb') as outfile:
    csv_log = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
    phoneme = []

    with open("ref.txt" + file, 'r') as sylfile:
        for lines in sylfile:
            row_sylfile = lines.split()
            start, end, syl = float(row_sylfile[0]), float(row_sylfile[1]), row_sylfile[2]

            with open("hyp.txt", 'r') as phnfile:
                data = []
                for line in phnfile:
                    row_phnfile = line.split()
                    startphn, endphn, sylphn = float(row_phnfile[0]), float(row_phnfile[1]), row_phnfile[2]

                    if (startphn >= start) and (endphn <= end) and (startphn < endphn):
                        phoneme.append(sylphn)
                        #print sylphn
                        data.extend([startphn, start, endphn, end])

                #print file,syl,' '.join(phoneme)
                csv_log.writerow(data + [file, syl] + phoneme)
                phoneme = []
```

I would recommend using the `csv` library to build your rows. It can then be made to automatically add spaces between each of your entries. All you need to do is give it a single list of values (strings or floats).

This would give you a file starting:

```
0.0 0.0 0.33 0.33  !SIL SIL
0.33 0.33 0.46 0.67 0.46 0.33 0.67 0.67  非 F EI
0.67 0.67 0.79 0.95 0.79 0.67 0.87 0.95 0.87 0.67 0.95 0.95  生 SH AH NG
0.95 0.95 1.11 1.11  物 U
1.11 1.11 1.24 1.24  物 U
1.24 1.24 1.37 1.62 1.37 1.24 1.62 1.62  體 T I
1.62 1.62 1.68 1.74 1.68 1.62 1.74 1.74  也 I E
1.74 1.74 1.81 1.9 1.81 1.74 1.87 1.9 1.87 1.74 1.9 1.9  會 H U EI
1.9 1.9 1.94 2.06 1.94 1.9 2.06 2.06  有 I OU
2.06 2.06 2.18 2.18  一 I
2.18 2.18 2.27 2.46 2.27 2.18 2.4 2.46 2.4 2.18 2.46 2.46  種 ZH O NG
```

Comment: It worked like a charm thanks for the help, and also for letting me know my mistakes in formatting the question.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick mark under the up/down arrows to accept an answer as the accepted solution.